# .net test if point in polygon

Tags: c#, .net, gps

I'm developping an app that receive GPS position from a GPS Device.
This part is ok.

In my app, i got a list of Polygon and i want to test for each position in witch polygon my position is.

My polygon are in text format : "30.5,15.6;25.4,15; ..."

I ask witch librairie i could use to determinate if my GPS position is in thoses Polygon.

To do that, i have add the reference to System.Spatial but i don't understand how i can create a new GeometryPolygon and wich method i could use after to determinate if my point is in a polygon.

Comment: In Winforms (or GDI+) you can create a GraphicsPath from the polygon and  do the check with gp.Isvisible(point) - Note that you are not allowed to ask for libraries here!

Comment: When i talk about librairies i just want to mean some code reference about microsoft, because i can't find how i can create a new Polygon with there System.Spatial librairi.
For your answer i just want to know what i can use to create a GraphicPolygon.

Comment: What are you targetting? I don't know WPF nor System.Spatial; GraphicsPath is in Winforms and I guess you could include a few namespaces like `System.Drawing,  System.Drawing.Drawing2D;` and maybe one ot two more.. Note however that gp is only 2d!

Comment: Like i said sorry if i wasn't clear enought. My app get a position from a GPS device. I just want to check if this position is in a polygon.
I don't want special interface for that any map nothing i just want a way to create an object polygon and a function that return true or false if my point is in the polygon.
I gonna watch the System.Drawing, and Drawing2D if it could do the work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If working in **2D** in good enough you can use the `GraphicsPath` from `System.Drawing.Drawing2D`.

This is a minimal example of using a `GraphicsPath` in a `Console` application:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
        points.Add(new PointF(30.5f, 15.6f));
        points.Add(new PointF(25.4f, 5f));
        points.Add(new PointF(0, 20));

        float y = 11f;
        for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
        if (IsInPolygon(points, new PointF(x, y))) 
            Console.WriteLine("(" + x + ", y) is inside");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public static bool IsInPolygon(List<PointF> points, PointF location)
    {
        using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            gp.AddPolygon(points.ToArray());
            return gp.IsVisible(location);
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to add a reference to `System.Drawing`.